# How fix SettingWithCopyWarning with Pandas DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings, decision-tree

I'm coding my own decision tree model, and I have a *SettingWithCopyWarning* from Pandas I can't fix.
The decision tree have nodes that being interrogated to know what is the best node at a point of the decision tree. Each node (which is a class) creates his method for giving a label to each data and stores its method.
For example, I have nodes which deals with discret data and they basically store each label of possible data in a group.

```
class DiscreteNode(Node):
def __init__(self, name, n_classes,
    rank=None, groups=[]):
    super().__init__(name, n_classes, rank)
    self.groups = groups
```

They have a basic method (called get_split_index) which returns the index if it find the data value in a group, thus giving a label to that data, like this:

```
def get_split_index(self, value):
    for group in self.groups:
        if value in group:
            return self.groups.index(group)
```

The decision tree is trained with a Pandas DataFrame (the name of a node is a column of the DataFrame), which is splited at each node. So I need, for chosing a node, to estimate the performance of splitting of each node. For this, I need to process the label for each node for the whole DataFrame.
It seems simple, I tried to do something like this :

```
node = DiscreteNode(......)
col_to_process = df[col_variable_of_the_node]
labels = node.get_split_index([val for val in col_to_process])
df["label"] = labels
```

And it works like I wanted... but it raises a *SettingWithCopyWarning*

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-`docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy`
df["label"] = labels
```

Of course, I tried to do :

```
df.loc[:,"label"] = labels
```

But it doesn't fix the problem..

I did some researches I understood that the problem is I affect a value (set method with `df["labels"]`) which comes from a chaining process (take the column of a dataframe and then take each value). But I don't see how I can do it in another way.

I tried this, hoping it will fix the problem:

```
node = DiscreteNode(......)
col_to_process = df[col_variable_of_the_node]
series = df[col_to_process].values.tolist()
labels = [node.get_split_index(val) for val in series]
df["label"] = labels
```

But still have a *SettingWithCopyWarning*, I don't understand how pandas can identify the chaining after transforming the pandas column in list, but it does.

How can I fix this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I found it

I simply added this line and no more warnings:

```
node = DiscreteNode(......)
col_to_process = df[col_variable_of_the_node]
labels = node.get_split_index([val for val in col_to_process])
df_with_label = df.copy()
df_with_label["label"] = labels
```

Comment: Why does that line remove the warning?